# How to get verification code for google calendar api

Tags: php, oauth, calendar

I try to use the php quickstart provided by Google for the calendar api. ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php )
I created an OAuth-key, provided all the necessary data to the quickstart and everything looked fine until i was requested to provide the "verification code".
After properly configuring the quickstart with the OAuth credentials i started the quickstart file by command line and was provided by an url which i have to call in the browser and there i should retrieve a "verification code" which i shall put into the quickstart input. But whenever i open this url i am asked by google to allow the access and after allowing i am directly forwarded to the url set up in the OAuth token.
I never see any code which resembles to the requested "verification code".
How can i get this verification code and complete the quickstart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case somebody else made the same mistake. The verification code is part of the URL which you are redirected to.
Example redirect url: http://example.com/?code=4/g2kObgRwnDZnrpAo-enBrGhtaHTTXXXXjiCLMxuXXaU#
The Code is then "4/g2kObgRwnDZnrpAo-enBrGhtaHTTXXXXjiCLMxuXXaU#".

Comment: Hello,  I have Enter this code but still, it showing me Error, could you please help me out.

Error is:Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\quickstart.php(84): getClient() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on line 177